# Boundary value problem with Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

Let us consider the classical elliptic problem
$$ - u'' + u = f{\text{ in }}(0,1)$$
with boundary conditions $${u_x}(0) = {u_x}(1) = 0$$
It is well known that the previous problem admits unique solution in $H^1(0,1)$, but it seems to me that we can do better if we consider the space $$V = \left\{ {v \in {H^1}(0,1),{u_x}(0) = {u_x}(1) = 0} \right\}$$
Why we ignore the boundry condition in this case? thanks.

Comment: You should write down clearly what a weak solution is. You'll see that the boundary conditions are used to determine the notion of weak solution.

Answer (score 5):

Because for $u\in H^1(0,1)$, the values $u_x(0)$ and $u_x(1)$ are not well-defined, as $u_x\in L^2(0,1)$.